# How can I drop a Set in SSAS?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx, olap

I use `SQL Server 2008 R2` and `SSAS` and `AdventureWork` DataBase.

I write this `MDX Query` but i get this error because i do not create this `Set` before execute.

```
-- select from named set
Select
    [Europe] on columns
From [Adventure Works]
Where 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]

Executing the query ...
Query (3, 6) The dimension '[Europe]' was not found in the cube when the string,
[Europe], was parsed.

Execution complete
```

I use this `mdx query` for create a `Set`.

```
create 
set [Adventure Works].[Europe] as
    {
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].[France],
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].[Germany],
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].[United Kingdom]
    }
```

And then i use from this `Set` in my `MDX Query`

```
-- select from named set
Select
    [Europe] on columns
From [Adventure Works]
Where 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
```

[image]

And then i drop this `Set`

```
-- drop set

drop set [Adventure Works].[Europe]
```

But if i use from this `Set` i will have a result?!?

[image]

Why my set do not drop completely?

Comment: Did you process the cube after dropping it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a member in the SalesTerritory dimension with a value of Europe that is being used when no set is defined. When you create a set with the same name, it is used instead. Dropping the set will cause the query to use the Europe value again.

I'm not sure why you get the initial error. Make sure you run the query against the right database and cube.

It can be tricky to figure out what dimension the value is coming from. Luckily SQL Profiler can be of help.
[image]